# Show just a two or three days view on OSX Lion's iCal

Tags: osx-lion, calendar.app

On Snow Leopard version of iCal it was possible to show 2 or 3 days on iCal using CMD+ALT+2 or 3. On OSX Lion this is not possible using the same keys, do you know about any other workaround for this?